# Como hago un ranking de palabras repetidas en Python?

Tags: python, string

lo que quiero es Armar un ranking de palabras, informando palabra y cantidad de ocurrencias, ordenado por la cantidad de ocurrencias.

Mi idea es que empiece asi:

```
texto = input("ingrese texto: ").split()
```

Luego una vez que tengo la lista armada quiero que me tire algo como esto:

1- "hola" fue repetida 15 veces

2- "como" fue repetida 10 veces

3- "estas" fue repetida 5 veces

4- "?" fue repetida 1 veces

PD: lo quise armar con un `for` y me sale cualqueir cosa... porfavor los mas experimentados no usen cosas muy complicadas/avanzadas, cuanto mas básico mejor :) Desde ya gracias!!

Answer (score 3):

Usar `list.count` como propone @Juan en su respuesta es una posibilidad, pero tiene el inconveniente de recorrer la lista al completo una vez por cada palabra, lo cual es importante si nos preocupa la eficiencia.

Normalmente, la mejor aproximación es usar un diccionario como propone @Luis Alejandro en su respuesta. Si no se trata de una tarea o algo por el estilo, Python ya tiene algo pensado para hacer justamente esto y listo para usar, [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter).

```
texto = 'peras manzanas tomates peras tomates tomates'

import collections

counter = collections.Counter(texto.split())
for palabra, cont in counter.most_common():
    print(f"'{palabra}' aparece {cont} {'veces' if cont > 1 else 'vez'}.")
```

el método `most_comons` retorna una lista de parejas ordenada en función del orden de apariciones, de mayor a menor.

Salida:

> 'tomates' aparece 3 veces.
>   'peras' aparece 2 veces.
>   'manzanas' aparece 1 vez.

Comment: Uff jaja como recien estoy empezando con Python me base en cosas que usaba en otros lenguajes y no busco este tipo de funciones, me la guardo para ahorrar codigo, pero bueno, practique para que me salga, tenes mi voto porque es mejor tu respuesta

Answer (score 2):

Puedes usar un diccionario, no se que tan complejo pueda ser en este momento para ti, pero igual puedes probarlos, los diccionarios son estructuras que cuentan con una `clave` y un `valor`, y pueden ser útiles para casos como estos, ya que las claves no se pueden repetir.

```
cadena = "hola como estas como estas estas"
palabras = cadena.split(" ")
diccionario = dict()

for p in palabras:
    diccionario[p] = diccionario.get(p, 0) + 1

print(diccionario)
```

la salida es la siguiente `{'hola': 1, 'como': 2, 'estas': 3}`, el metodo `get` del diccionario obtiene el valor de la `clave`(primer parametro), y un valor `default` en caso de no existir la clave en el diccionario(segundo parametro) como puedes ver se comportan de una manera similar a una `lista`, en la cual sus indices pueden ser cadenas, que viene bien para este caso, de esta manera si quieres saber el numero de veces que se repite una palabra, puedes hacer lo siguiente `diccionario["palabra"]` o `diccionario.get("palabra", 0)` para evitar errores al no existir la palabra

Answer (score 1):

Importo operator para poder ordenar luego el array que se me va a armar de palabra + veces que se repite.

CadenaPalabras es el valor que se va a tomar del input.

Al valor que llega lo paso a minuscula y le hago un split para separarlos (Los paso a minuscula porque si pongo 'Esto' y 'esto' es la misma palabra, asi no se repite, si las tenes que diferenciar solo saca el .lower().

Creo un array donde van a ir las frecuencias de cada palabra, luego recorro las palabras separadas y voy contando cuantas veces se repitieron y voy guardando esos numeros en el array de frecuencia.

Luego creo un array de repeticiones ahi guardo la palabra y las veces que se repitieron unidas ej: ('aparece', 4).

Luego con set elimino los duplicados.

Luego los ordenos con sorted en base a la segunda posicion de cada array que seria la posicion 1 ej: el 4 ('aparato', 4).

Y luego como ya esta ordenado el array y contado solo lo recorro y lo muestro.

```
import operator

cadenaPalabras = '''Esto es una prueba esto no aquello tampoco esto menos ni hablar de esto menos que menos que menos'''

listaPalabras = cadenaPalabras.lower().split()

frecuenciaPalab = []
for w in listaPalabras:
    frecuenciaPalab.append(listaPalabras.count(w))

repeticiones = []

for x in range(0, len(listaPalabras)):
    repeticiones.append((listaPalabras[x], frecuenciaPalab[x]))

myList = list(set(repeticiones))

myList = sorted(myList, key=operator.itemgetter(1), reverse=True)


for x in range(0, len(myList)):
    print('La palabra ' + myList[x][0] + ' aparece ' + str(myList[x][1]) + ' veces.')
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y si queres la pasas a funcion y la reutilizas:

```
import operator

def ordenar(cadena):
    listaPalabras = cadena.lower().split()

    frecuenciaPalab = []
    for w in listaPalabras:
        frecuenciaPalab.append(listaPalabras.count(w))

    repeticiones = []

    for x in range(0, len(listaPalabras)):
        repeticiones.append((listaPalabras[x], frecuenciaPalab[x]))

    myList = list(set(repeticiones))
    myList = sorted(myList, key=operator.itemgetter(1), reverse=True)

    for x in range(0, len(myList)):
        print('La palabra ' + myList[x][0] + ' aparece ' + str(myList[x][1]) + ' veces.')



cadenaUno = '''Esto es una prueba esto no aquello tampoco esto menos ni hablar de esto menos que menos que menos'''
cadenaDos = '''Hola Hola Hola Chau Chau Chau zero zero zero zero zero'''
cadenaTres = '''nUEVO nUeVo NUEVo Viejo VieJO VIEJO viejo ViEjO'''
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: listaPalabras.count(w) eso es un contador que agrega la cantidad de veces que se repite en la lista y lo mete en otra lista llamada frecuenciaPalab? Fijate que ademas no queda como un ranking, aparece Esto priemero y luego vuelve a aparecer otra vez, aunque esta cerca

Comment: Si lo estoy modificando ahi estoy haciendo que no muestre repetidos, ahi hago el ranking

Comment: Ahi lo modifique

Answer (score 1):

Tomi, en el ejemplo, la variable **datos** es el equivalente a la lista de palabras ingresada, y luego separada con el split. La deje de este modo para simplificar las pruebas.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

datos = ["oveja", "perro", "caballo", "oveja", "perro", "perro",
         "caballo", "perro", "gato", "gato", "tardígrado", "jurel"
         ]
clasificacion = {}

for dato in datos:
  if dato in clasificacion:
    clasificacion[dato] += 1
  else:
    clasificacion[dato] = 1

plt.bar(range(len(clasificacion)), list(clasificacion.values()), align='center') 
plt.xticks(range(len(clasificacion)), list(clasificacion.keys()))
plt.show()
```